# How an application detects on its launch the reason which made it launch?

Tags: java, javafx

I have created an ImageViewer using javafx for browsing and editing images. This appn provides an open menu to select image files to be browsed. I converted the .jar file into .exe file. In properties of one image file I changed the option "open with" so that the image now by default opens using this ImageViewer. But when I double click the image, appn ImageViewer launches and doea nothing as theres no coding for such things. The only way to view image is to use the "open menu". But I want the functionality that on clicking of the image, the appn ImageViewer launches and displays the image. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: How about an [mcve] ?

Comment: @c0der For example : If in windows you double click some text file, it is opened with notepad. Notepad opens and displays the contents of file. My question is how notepad detects that file? And if I have to do the same using java then is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, there is a way to do this since we know other applications can do it - we just have to identify what it is.

I have done something similar before, so allow me to walk you through my thinking regarding how to find the answer and then I think it will be clear.

Consider the problem - you have an operating system trying to talk to an application such that it will tell the app which file to open. Logically we must conclude that the system must send the app a path to that file.

Now, how would the communication take place? Let's think about setting default programs - are there any limitations there or can you ask any program to open any kind of file? If you experiment a bit you'll find that there are no restrictions - you can ask any program to open any file (not saying it will work correctly, but it can be done). So what does that tell us? It means the system has no idea which programs are the "correct" ones to open files and this suggests there is no registration mechanism where you would have to say to the system "Hey, I can open this kind of file".

So, if any program can open any file and the system does not maintain a registry of programs that can open files how would you think it would talk to a program to communicate the file path it should open? Well, the simplest most generic way would seem to be with command line arguments. This way all the system does is invoke the application and pass an argument containing the file path.

When you define your main method: `public static void main(String[] args){...}` the "args" parameter is where the command line arguments are being passed to your program. If you write some log statements and/or System.out statements to dump the contents of the args I bet you'll find that the file path is being passed this way.

Once you confirm that you can obtain the file path through the args then you just have to write your file reading logic such that is uses the argument passed in by the system to find and read the file contents.

Comment: Thanks alot, it did help. Now I have done the required coding and its working fine.